# SpriteKit Issue with Double Jump only working some of the time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Code:

```
func jumpAction(_ JumpPos: CGPoint, _ clickPos: CGPoint) {
    if jumpCount < 2 {
        var disty = (clickPos.y - JumpPos.y)
        var distx = clickPos.x

        self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        self.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: distx, dy: disty))

        if  onGround == false {
            jumpCount += 1
        }
    }
}//

func didBegin(_ other: SKSpriteNode, _ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if contact.contactPoint.y < self.frame.minY + 10 {
        jumpCount = 1
        onGround = true
    }
    if other.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == Mask.SpinPlat {
        jumpCount = 0
    }
}

func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    onGround = false
}
```

I have 3 functions above. The JumpAction is called when I press on the Jump Button on the screen. The didBegin and didEnd functions are called when contact with the top of a platform occurs with the player.

**My issue:**

So if player is on platform and I jump, the jump action is called before the didEnd function. This is why I have the jumpCount set to 1 when the player contacts the platform. This works fine...

The real issue is when my player lands on the platform, and he bounces slightly off (due to restitution) and then the jump button is pressed.

When this occurs, the onGround flag is flipped to false before the jump action is called and my player can only single jump.

I'm trying to find a simple way to get around this issue without having to implement a bunch of code, haven't found a way yet.

So this is why I am here. I want to be able to double jump even with that slight little bounce I explained earlier.

Thank you in advance!!!

**Additional Info:**
I use the onGround flag so that if the player is on the ground, he can slide along the ground if they press the jump button in the right location...

Comment: What, exactly, is the "dined function?"

Comment: the DidEnd function? it is called when the player object looses contact with the platform.

Comment: Got it. You might want to edit your question - "is called before the dined function"

Comment: oh my bad. Ya I just fixed it.

Comment: You do not want to set your `onGround = false` on your didEnd phase. you want to set it as soon as you accelerate when your distY > 0, so basically  `if(distY > 0) {onGround = false}`. Note, this is not the same as `onGround = (distY > 0`) because this would imply that he is on the ground, when he may not be

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is with onGround changing in didEnd function. The whole reason I use the onGround function is so that I can slide my player left or right with the jump button. Depending on the location I press within the jump button will determine the direction player goes. If player doesn't lift off the platform, then he can slide left or right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply delaying setting the "on ground" flag by a fraction of a second?

```
let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)
scene.runAction(waitAction, completion: {
                  self.onGround = false

            })
```

Obviously you could experiment with the exact duration to make sure it gives the "bounce" just enough time to end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. that would eliminate the issue. But I would prefer it if the player is capable of jumping as soon as possible. I can update the question if that seems appropriate?

Comment: I don't think it would affect his ability to jump a second time, as when jump is called the second time, onGround has not yet been set to false (it gets set a fraction of a second later). Isn't that the very problem you are trying to solve?

Again, you might want to tweak the half second I've hard coded here, but I'm pretty certain this will give you the exact behavior you are looking for.

Comment: oh I see what you mean. I misinterpreted the code. It works, but then causes issues with the jumps. If the duration is too long, you can jump multiple times before it registers a jump. And if it is too short, sometimes I'm only able to jump 1 time instead of the 2 times. It is a good idea, but I'm not sure that it will work In my situation.

Comment: If you post a github link to more of the code, I might be able to look at another solution. Hard to do with just what you've posted.

Comment: I appreciate the help so far, I'll keep looking for a solution. I am using the onGround flag as a way of enabling sliding without incrementing the jump counter. I think I have a solution I can try here in a few.

Comment: I found a fix. I used your function to delay the check on the onGround flag within the jumpAction function.

Comment: I also changed the didBegin function to reset the jumpCount to 0. Because of the delay when checking the flag in jumpAction, it gave time for the didEnd function to actually change the value.

Comment: fantastic. Feel free to mark up my response as an answer ;)

Comment: You should really be using SKActions.wait(forDuration: ... ) instead of DispatchQueue in a SpriteKit game.

Comment: this is not a good approach. What happens when you pause the scene in the middle of this delay?  Your delay will still fire, even though the game is in a paused state

Comment: I like the SKAction way, I didn't even think of that as an option. If you post the answer I'll mark it as correct. I definitely think this is the better way of doing it.

Comment: Agreed. Answer revised to use SKAction.waitForDuration and a completion block.

Comment: Works like a charm with 0.1 sec delay. Thanks for the help everyone!